# Android device 'unauthorized' only in recovery mode

Tags: android, adb, root

when i run `abd devices` when the device is in the normal OS mode, it's authorized. then i run `adb reboot recovery` to get into recovery, and suddenly it's unauthorized.

it's a scepter 8 tablet (gen 2, MD) running android 12 go. any help?

i've tried turning usb debugging on and off, restarting the adb server, resetting authorizations, using windows & linux, running everything as sudo, rebooting the device, deleting the keys for it to regenerate them, but nothing has worked.
i haven't tried going into the system and making the keys file manually, because my device is not rooted. i need to fix this to root it (i'm trying to grab the boot.img of the device)

Comment: Regular OS and recovery are two independent OS, so it is not unexpected that you are unauthorized in the one and authorized in the other. On stock devices the recovery has only very limited functionality, what you are trying to do?